# JavaScript array shuffler not working

Tags: javascript, shuffle

I tried to write some javascript that takes the entries of an array and shuffles the order. It's not compiling like it should though. Seems to only run through the for loop once. What am I missing?

```
//random number between 1 and num
function randInt(num){
    return Math.floor(num*Math.random()+1);
}

//shuffles deck (array) of any size
function shuffle(array){
    var newArray = new Array();
    var n = array.length;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        var entry = randInt(array.length) - 1;
        newArray[i] = array[entry]; //assigns random entry in initial array to       new array
            array = array.splice(entry, 1); //removes the entry that was stored into newArray
    }
    array = newArray;
}
```

Comment: Declare "i" with `var`!!! Also that's a  really wasteful way to shuffle, even if you do manage to get it to work. Check out the [Fisher-Yates shuffle article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) at wikipedia. No reason to call `.slice()`.

Comment: And declare `var entry` outside of the loop .. oh what the hell, just run JSLint man :P

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: I disagree, `entry` is not used outside of the loop and JS has no problems with multiple var statements. It's true that all variables are scoped to the function but I prefer to keep it inside the loop, that tells the next developer that it is only meant to be used in the loop.

Comment: I suppose that's a fair enough argument. If you know about scoping I'll save you the lecture ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `array.splice` modifies `array` and returns the removed item(s). You want to discard the element, so just do this instead of overwriting `array`:

```
array.splice(entry, 1);
```

- `+ 1` in `randInt` and doing `- 1` afterwards seems superflouous.
- Use `var i = 0` (though look at my last point).
- Use `[]` instead of `new Array()` since the latter is not generally used.
- Return the new array instead of overwriting `array`:

```
return newArray;
```

- You modify `array` so you cannot loop up to `n` anymore as the length becomes 1 less each time. You may want `while(array.length > 0) { ... }` instead of the `for` loop.

Comment: Agh! Of course. I feel foolish for not picking up on the lack of var in front of the i. randInt is used elsewhere where I need a positive integer otherwise I would have made this adjustment. As to your last point, I set the initial length of the array to circumvent this problem, but I agree that your while loop is much cleaner. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental problem you're having here is that your code is written as if JavaScript were a call-by-reference language. It's not; it's call-by-value.  Thus, the last line of the function is syntactically correct but functionally useless.

Here's the Fisher-Yates shuffle:

```
function fyShuffle(a) {
  if (a.length < 2) return;
  for (var i = a.length; --i >= 1; ) {
   var j = ~~(Math.random() * (i + 1)), tmp;
   tmp = a[j];
   a[j] = a[i];
   a[i] = tmp;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont need to re-invent the wheel (in this case the shuffle).

```
function shuffle(o){
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
}
```

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/849

Comment: This seems to suffer from the issue posted [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use array.sort with a custom function?

```
function shuffle(array) {
    array.sort(function(a, b) {
        return (Math.random() < 0.5) ? 1 : -1;
    });
}
```

Comment: This is a terrible way to shuffle.

Comment: ... more: the reasons that it's terrible are several.  You don't really know what the sort will do, so it's hard to say whether every element will definitely be sorted. It's expensive because of the function calls.  Also, because the comparison of any two elements my be different when they're compared more than once, the sort could get very confused and may not terminate.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.shuffle= function(){
    var i, L= this.length;
    while(--L){
        i= Math.floor(Math.random()*L);
        this[L]= this.splice(i, 1, this[L])
    }
    return this;
}
```

Hard to say if using splice is quicker than direct assignment-

```
Array.prototype.shuffle= function(){
    var i, temp, L= this.length;
    while(--L){
        i= Math.floor(Math.random()*L);
        temp= this[i];
        this[i]= this[L];
        this[L]= temp;
    }
    return this;
}
```